# NSError, при ошибке связи с интернетом - краш приложения, как отлаживать NSUrlConnection?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Шлю POST запросы так:

```
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&act=login&login=%@&hash=%@", TextLogin.text, hashmd];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request121 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request121 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.ru/?go=service"]];
    [request121 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request121 setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
    NSData *GETReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request121 returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (error)
{
//Ошибочка да?
}

    NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[GETReply bytes] length:[GETReply length] encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];
```

В случае реальной ошибки (нет интернета или недоступен сервер) - краш приложения, как избежать?

Comment: Краш в каком месте, в `NSString *theReply = ...` ? Как обрабатываете ошибку?

Comment: Сейчас заметил что краша нет, срабатывает if (error), никак не обрабатываю, торможу метод (return) обычно.

Comment: aknew, не хотелось бы создавать новый вопрос, так что спрошу в этом: как можно сжимать изображение перед отправкой его на сервер, допустим, если привышает 5000 кб?"

Comment: Насколько помню, родной сжималки в сдк нету, так что какой-то сторонней библиотекой придется. Под айось точно есть zlib (использовал сто лет назад), и, кажется, bzip2, но конкретного решения или кода у меня нету.

Comment: Спасибо, погуглю)